# Which is more robust against temperature cycles, solder or wire wrap?

Tags: soldering, temperature, wire, reliability

When connecting a bunch of components in something that will be subject to repeated heating and cooling, are soldered joints likely to be more or less robust than wire wrap?

Intuitively, it feels like wire wrap should be more resilient, but I'm not certain of that conclusion, and a poster here suggests otherwise: https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/tubes-valves/287205-vacuum-tubes-wire-wrap.html

> However, after much experimentation, it became clear that wire wrap was only good for the short term, by itself. If the piece of built-stuff flexed much, then eventually oxidation would set in and make some one of the hidden dozens-to-hundreds of connections vexingly noisy. And never when debugging.

Is that correct, or is wire wrap likely to be more robust if done better? Or are there other factors to consider?

Comment: I have always read that wire wrap is extremely reliable if it is done correctly. The wire wrap excludes oxygen so there should not be oxidation at the interface. But even though I am defending wire wrap, I would much rather put my trust in a soldered PCBA, just for ease of assembly. These are just opinions.

Comment: For repeated cooling/heating, you need to consider humidity which in turn causes oxidation. For such environments soldering is preferred. And also some manner of PCB coating.

Comment: @Lundin Why does repeated cooling/heating require consideration of humidity? Because cooling will increase the relative humidity? I was under the impression that properly done wire wrap creates gas tight joints, is that not the case? Or is there some reason those do not protect against humidity?

Comment: When done properly, the wire wrap wire will be deformed by the sharp corner of the square post creating a gas-tight seal. I have 40 year-old wire wrap boards that still work. Both are reliable, reliability should not be the primary reason for your choice.

Comment: @rwallace What happens when you cool hot air, or when you take a cold object and move it to a warmer location? You get moisture, which is the death of all electronics and is generally unkind to most metal surfaces as well. This is why gold plating is used for connectors, because gold is much less sensitive to oxidation much better than tin or copper etc. For high-reliably PCBs you even use gold-plated pads.

Comment: Space flight uses welded joints in preference to either when it can. A well-done wirewrap joint should exclude gases from the interface and so prevent corrosion, just as a well-made solder joint should last for a long time. Solder has so many other advantages over wrap that you'd have to have good evidence of solder's unreliability for your particular application and temperature range to pick anything else.

Comment: @Neil_UK What are the other advantages of solder over wrap? I have been getting the impression that in cases where both are applicable, wrap is quicker and easier to do, easier to repair if a component fails, and more resilient against things like vibration. What am I missing?

Comment: @rwallace size and weight are the most obvious, wire wrap pins more than double the height and weight of a board. I have been bitten by a wire-wrap intermittency where the wire fractured within the insulation of the last turn, which hid the break. In normal operation, the thermal expansion of the plastic insulation moved the wire in and out of contact as the temperature changed. Took ages to find. The customer insisted on wrap because it was 'more reliable'!

Comment: @rwallace What you are missing is context "Easier and quicker?" How exactly? In what cases? To make one board? Or a thousand boards? A board with 100 connections? A board with 10,000 connections?

Comment: @DKNguyen Suppose it's 10,000 connections, which is quicker and more reliable then?

Comment: Reflow soldering on a PCB because you solder all the connections simultaneously and could use software to keep track of and set the connections is definitely easier and more reliable in the sense of protecting you from your own mistakes. Now if you assume the boards are magically and perfectly assembled with equal effort, I can't really weigh in on the reliability at that point other than to say for vibration, mass = bad, high parts count = bad.

Comment: It is hard for me to imagine that you would even have the option of wire wrapping a board nowadays. Are you going to put all your parts in sockets? Most of the components I use are in SMT only, so it would not be possible for me to design for wire wrap. So even if it is more reliable for thermal cycling, are you sure you even have the option?